# Вывод ветки дерева категорий

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется 3 таблицы:

1. `store (id,name)` - таблица магазинов
2. `category (id,parent_id,name)` - таблица категорий неограниченной вложенности
3. `store_category_rel (id, store_id, category_id)` - таблица связи магазин->категория

Необходимо вывести именно ту ветку до подкатегории, которая указана в таблице `store_category_rel`.

```
$id_shop=10;    // id нужного магазина

$cats=array();
$result=array();

function build_tree($cats,$pid,$only_parent = false){
    if(is_array($cats) and isset($cats[$pid])){
        $tree = '<ul>';
        if($only_parent==false){
            foreach($cats[$pid] as $cat){
                $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'];
                $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
                $tree .= '</li>';
            }
        }elseif(is_numeric($only_parent)){
            $cat = $cats[$pid][$only_parent];
            $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'];
            $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
        $tree .= '</ul>';
    }
    else return null;
    return $tree;
}

function find_parent($tmp, $cur_id){
    if($tmp[$cur_id][0]['pid']!=0){
        return find_parent($tmp,$tmp[$cur_id][0]['pid']);
    }
    return (int)$tmp[$cur_id][0]['id'];
}


$row=$base->query("SELECT * FROM category");
foreach($row AS $row){
    $cats_ID[$row['id']][] = $row;
    $cats[$row['pid']][$row['id']]= $row;
}

$row=$base->query("SELECT * FROM store_category_rel WHERE store_id='$id_shop'");
foreach($row AS $row){
    $res=build_tree($cats,0,find_parent($cats_ID,$row['bsc_id']));

    if(!in_array($res,$result)){
        $result[]=$res;
    }
}

foreach($result AS $result){
    print $result;
}
```

Пример как должно быть:
из категорий выводится такой массив дерева
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используя таблицу связей должено получится следующий массив дерева
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы уже сделали для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Добавил в описание.

Comment: Ну хорошо, а что не получается то? Что именно не работает? Как проявляется ошибка? Как ее воспроизвести?

Comment: Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.